# Convert to buffer in Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to pass text from client to server using socket and I'll take that text from an EditText in Android Studio but I don't know how to pass this text to buffer so I can pass it to the server and when I tried to convert the text coming from the view to string then to buffer it gives me an error saying that I can't convert from an editable text to string

```
       send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
       message =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.message);
```

the send is the button that will take the message and send it and the message is the text that I want to send.

Answer (score 1):

Java 7/Android API 19

```
message.getText().toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

If that isn't available you need to do this

```
message.getText().toString().getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

The second one throws a RuntimeException if UTF-8 doesn't exist.

---

[public Editable getText ()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#getText()) From **android.widget.EditText**

> Return the text the TextView is displaying. If setText() was called with an argument of BufferType.SPANNABLE or BufferType.EDITABLE, you can cast the return value from this method to Spannable or Editable, respectively. Note: The content of the return value should not be modified. If you want a modifiable one, you should make your own copy first.

This method returns [android.text.Editable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html) which implements [java.lang.CharSequence](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/CharSequence.html) which overrides [java.lang.Object.toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) that returns a string representation of the object. Once you have a String representation you can call [java.lang.String.getBytes()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes()) or any of its overloads to converting it to bytes in the charset you want. This line of code above just does everything in one line and returns the resulting byte array.

Comment: It's best if you add some commentary and not just toss code out there.

Comment: @ParkashKumar This is pretty straight forward. He just missed to toString() method, so I didn't think it was necessary.

Comment: But you have two changes in your code. toString() and getBytes(). You should have mentioned what is the purpose of doing that for better understanding.

Comment: The no-argument overload of [`getBytes()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes--) is a poor choice: it encodes using the platform default encoding, which can vary between computers, and it has unspecified behavior when it encounters characters it can't encode.  A better choice is the overload that takes a string naming a character encoding (such as "UTF-8"); unfortunately, calling that overload requires you to add a try/catch block to the call, even if the encoding named is guaranteed to be supported by the JVM implementation, as is the case for UTF-8.

Comment: @PeterO. You're right, updated it. No need for Exception if you have Java 7 thanks to [java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you use native Java sockets, you can use this code.

```
OutputStream outstream = socket.getOutputStream(); 
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(outstream);
writer.print(message.getText().toString());
```

Using this way, you won't need to convert everything into bytes.